# Find Matrix $T$ for $D = \begin{bmatrix}1& 1 \\ -1 & 3\end{bmatrix}. $

Tags: matrices

Find the matrix $T$ that puts $A$ in canonical form.

one eigenvalue I found is $2$ with associated vector $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

How can I found the matrix $T$ with only one vector?

Comment: What does canonical form mean to you? There are a few.

Comment: It means there are three types of matrices that are canonical form

Comment: yes, since this is repeated eigenvalues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: To find the second linearly independent (generalized) eigenvector, set up and solve:

$$(A − \lambda I)v_2 = v_1$$

**Spoiler**

> $$v_2 = (-1,0)$$

Comment: is $\lambda$ = 2 in this case?

Comment: how to find $v_2$?

Comment: when I row reduce the following matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $, I get $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $ which never multiply another vector to get (1,1) which is $v_1$

Comment: I can solve 2x2 system to find your answer...However, it has been three years for me to do the RREF, could you show me the step

Comment: You end up with $ \begin{bmatrix}1& -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. This give $a = b - 1$. Let $b = 0$, so $a = -1$. Here are more examples if that is not clear

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf: Oops, forgot link: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~stecher/Linear-Algebra/Systems/examples.html